# Redirect for iphone in Rails/Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, sinatra

I am working on a  **rails + sinatra** mobile application in which I want to redirect to a specific location(page) on my server. I call a particular sinatra function (in controller which is in {app_root}/lib/ folder) in .rb file, which after performing some functionality render a specific view.

This works fine but when I want to redirect some other site like `www.google.com` from the controller, it gives me `Error: Loading Page error`.

I am using
`redirect "http://www.google.com"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails, the command you want to use is

```
redirect_to "http://google.com"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html